# Why this value in this recursion showing this value?

Tags: function, recursion

### My code is written below... It's a c++ code.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int fun (int a)
{
    if (a>=0)
        return a+fun(a-2);
}

int main()
{
    int x=12;
    printf("%d",fun(x));
    return 0;
}
```

---

In this code, shouldn't I suppose to see an output of 42 rather than having an output of 40?
Why it's showing 40 instead of 42. What is the logic behind this?

Comment: I haven't checked what the recursion should return, but you definitely have a bug because you don't explicitly return anything from `fun()` if a is less than 0.

Comment: This is exactly how my question was given. I just copied it from the paper and posted it here. We were supposed to calculate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that your actual code is:

```cpp
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int fun (int a)
{
    if (a>=0)
        return a+fun(a-2);
    return a; // may be missing.
}

int main()
{
    int x=12;
    printf("%d",fun(x));
    return 0;
}
```

The reason of why this code returns 40 is value of argument `a` at last time called `fun`
is `-2`. Because `if (a>=0)` is true when `a==0`.
So your program caclculates `12+10+8+6+4+2+0+ -2` (is equal 40).